# How to rotate the Bar graph(keeping axis constant) in tableau?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, tableau-api

I am learning tableau and I extracted the data from Mysql workbench and imported as CSV file and it looks as follows:

[image]

I wanted my output as:

[image]

But when I tried, I am getting the tableau view as:

[image]

I also tried to put `calendar year as Column and employee number as row`
In both the diagram the axis of calendar year and employee number are same but why the graph is coming different ,since the data is same for both graph.
So,I try by clicking `Cntrl+W` to rotate the graph but the axis got rotated( i don't want the axis to be rotated,only the bar graph needs to be vertical as I have shown my expected output).

[image]

(edited) When right clicking it is showing me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Drag the Employee number into rows and calendar Year drag to column then
Right click on calendar Year ->select the--> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqqM8.png)continuous

Comment: just see the last image i just uploaded now ..there is not select the continuous

Comment: if u have teamviewer plz can u connect in my desktop and see.. its continuous as default